# Confusion on how Golang pointers are preserved in structs

Tags: oop, pointers, go

I'm currently learning golang (mostly a Java/C# developer) and I hit an issue with pointers and defer.

I'm trying to wrap the writes to a CSV file under a struct in a OO-like style. From the examples I found online, it seems that creating "methods" on a struct could be done like so:

```
type MyObject struct {
    fp  *os.File
    csv *csv.Writer
}

func (mo MyObject) Open(filepath string) {

    println(&mo)
    var err error
    mo.fp, err = os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mo.csv = csv.NewWriter(mo.fp)
}
```

The problem I hit was once I left the Open method, the pointers for fp and csv went back to null. Subsequent calls to this class would throw a nil error. A full example can be found [here](https://play.golang.org/p/UixVUY9pbfT).

After a lot of googling, I ended up looking at how golang implemented their [logger](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/log/log.go). They used a pointer to the object like so:

```
type MyObject struct {
    fp  *os.File
    csv *csv.Writer
}

func New() *MyObject {
    return &MyObject{}
}

func (mo *MyObject) Open(filepath string) {

    println(&mo)
    var err error
    mo.fp, err = os.Create(filepath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mo.csv = csv.NewWriter(mo.fp)
}
```

A refactoring of my code (see [here](https://play.golang.org/p/HAMiycA7V1L)) shows it works as expected. I'm still confused though why the first method didn't work. I'm guessing I'm  misunderstanding something on how structs, pointers, and/or defer work. What am I missing?

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't work in the first case, because `func (mo MyObject) Open(filepath string)`  only got a local copy of `MyObject`...and all changes made to it remained within that context.

But after you added `*` to the receiver, i.e `(mo *MyObject)` the changes within the function affected the original MyObject.

[you can check here for more info](https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers)

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that FAQ, that makes a lot more sense!